# Not able to use Fontawesome as unordered-list list items in Wordpress Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, listitem

Im using this css to get fontawesome glyphs as list-item markers - ive used this in plain vanilla (non WordPress sites before without issue:

```
ul#lene-pages-list, #lene-pages-list li {
  padding    : 0;
  margin     : 0;
  list-style : none;
}

ul#lene-pages-list {
  margin : 2em 0;
}

#lene-pages-list li {
  margin      : 1em;
  margin-left : 3em;
}

#lene-pages-list li:before {
  content     : '\f005';
  font-family : 'FontAwesome';
  float       : left;
  margin-left : -1.5em;
  color       : #0074D9;
}
```

The result is small boxes displayed where the glyph should be indicating the code is not recognised ive tried about twenty different codes from Fontawesome 4.x which is installed and working everywhere else on the site (including the same page) so i know Fontawesome is supported and installed ok.

Ive read on the Fontawesome site [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list) that you adopt a pure html inline approach thus:

```
  <ul class="fa-ul">
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-star"></i></span>C#</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-star"></i></span>PHP</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-star"></i></span>ASP</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-star"></i></span>Cold Fusion</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-star"></i></span>Python</li>
    <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="far fa-star"></i></span>Pearl</li>
</ul>
```

The classes are Fontawesome specific. Wow this seems like a backward step is this still the case? im not sure how old the article is but i cant believe this is the way forward. I have over 80 pages to code by hand now to use their suggested method - isn't this exactly what css is for ... DRY

Comment: What method are you using to load Fontawesome? You seem to be saying that other FA glyphs are loading even on the same page, just not in a certain section of it or for list items? Can you link to the problem page?

Comment: Hi, 
I should have explained in the question i'm using WordPress with Woocommerce all within a WP Astra theme and i've just discovered WP Astra uses its own icon set and not FA (not without a plugin anyway). Inclusion in CSS is similar to that of FA but obviously classes are Astra specific - see : 
https://wpastra.com/docs/default-font-icon-list-in-astra/

Cheers for your input anyway.